# Swift How to add array of strings to httpBody

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire, urlsession

Normally we use dictionaries as parameters but to delete photo API that I work with needs just String name of that image in an array.

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 80
Authorization: Bearer [token]
["https://work-solution.s3.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com/job-83-image-gpfv7dfy.jpeg"]
```

I got the method to add single String to httpBody with Alamofire:

```
struct BodyStringEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    private let body: String

    init(body: String) { self.body = body }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        guard var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest else { throw Errors.emptyURLRequest }
        guard let data = body.data(using: .utf8) else { throw Errors.encodingProblem }
        urlRequest.httpBody = data
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

And that's fine but don't know how to make this body to be single string array and not just string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
let bodyData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: yourArray)
```

followed by

```
let bodyString = String(data: body, encoding: .utf8)
```

There is unwrapping, and do/catch to write, but you get the idea.

This line `guard let data = body.data(using: .utf8) else { throw Errors.encodingProblem }` can be simplified with `let data = Data(body.utf8)`, no need to unwrap.

Finally, since you are doing

```
Array 
-- JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: theArray) --> 
Data 
-- String(data: theData, encoding: .utf8) --> 
String 
-- Data(theString.utf8) --> 
Data
```

You might want to rewrite your object, avoiding unnecessary conversions:

```
struct BodyStringEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    private let body: Data

    init(body: String) { self.body = Data(body.utf8) }

    init(body: Data) { self.body = body }

    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        guard var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest else { throw Errors.emptyURLRequest }
        urlRequest.httpBody = self.body
        return urlRequest
    }
}
```